# Python: remove part of the data

Tags: python

The `data` actually consist of json(first part) and tuple(second part). When check the `type(data)` is return tuple. How to remove the tuple in the data and keep json (first part) only?

```
data = {'trades': [{'id': '9306', 'instrument': 'EUR_GBP', 'price': '0.83150', 'openTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:09.481201403Z', 'initialUnits': '462500', 'initialMarginRequired': '14637.9400', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '462500', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '70.0612', 'marginUsed': '14639.6050', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9307', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:09.839444208Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9306', 'price': '0.83648', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9308', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:10.154967972Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9306', 'price': '0.82857', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9302', 'instrument': 'USD_CAD', 'price': '1.27561', 'openTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:08.344902573Z', 'initialUnits': '-462500', 'initialMarginRequired': '13123.7321', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '-462500', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '414.6871', 'marginUsed': '13118.1486', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9303', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:08.760908757Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9302', 'price': '1.27060', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9304', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:09.114055042Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9302', 'price': '1.27856', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9286', 'instrument': 'GBP_JPY', 'price': '154.857', 'openTime': '2022-01-31T12:39:24.298934946Z', 'initialUnits': '4625', 'initialMarginRequired': '176.0756', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '4625', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '3.5046', 'marginUsed': '176.0330', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9287', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:39:24.608270603Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9286', 'price': '155.361', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9288', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:39:24.941634335Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9286', 'price': '154.556', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9278', 'instrument': 'AUD_USD', 'price': '0.70502', 'openTime': '2022-01-31T12:38:10.153106452Z', 'initialUnits': '462552', 'initialMarginRequired': '9251.0400', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '462552', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '45.6891', 'marginUsed': '9251.0400', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9279', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:38:10.457435278Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9278', 'price': '0.71004', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9280', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:38:10.765267979Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9278', 'price': '0.70230', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9229', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34505', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:01.767987144Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9310', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '-0.4036', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '9.4716', 'marginUsed': '28.3636', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9240', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:40:54.539350738Z', 'replacesOrderID': '9230', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9229', 'price': '1.50000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9231', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:02.589631870Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9229', 'price': '1.01000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9219', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34465', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:53.369040131Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9312', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '-0.4036', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '9.8884', 'marginUsed': '28.3636'}, {'id': '9216', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34454', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:41.086253690Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9355', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '-0.4036', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '10.0030', 'marginUsed': '28.3636', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9246', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T09:05:54.649091912Z', 'replacesOrderID': '9217', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9216', 'price': '1.50000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}}], 'lastTransactionID': '9308'}
([{'unrealizedPL': 70.0612, 'currentUnits': 462500, 'trade_id': 9306, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 44, 9, 481201, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'EUR_GBP'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 414.6871, 'currentUnits': -462500, 'trade_id': 9302, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 44, 8, 344902, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_CAD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 3.5046, 'currentUnits': 4625, 'trade_id': 9286, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 39, 24, 298934, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'GBP_JPY'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 45.6891, 'currentUnits': 462552, 'trade_id': 9278, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 38, 10, 153106, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'AUD_USD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 9.4716, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9229, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 8, 1, 1, 767987, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 9.8884, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9219, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 7, 45, 53, 369040, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 10.003, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9216, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 7, 45, 41, 86253, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'}],
 True)
```

The desired result is to remove the tuple part

```
([{'unrealizedPL': 70.0612, 'currentUnits': 462500, 'trade_id': 9306, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 44, 9, 481201, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'EUR_GBP'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 414.6871, 'currentUnits': -462500, 'trade_id': 9302, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 44, 8, 344902, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_CAD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 3.5046, 'currentUnits': 4625, 'trade_id': 9286, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 39, 24, 298934, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'GBP_JPY'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 45.6891, 'currentUnits': 462552, 'trade_id': 9278, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 38, 10, 153106, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'AUD_USD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 9.4716, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9229, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 8, 1, 1, 767987, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 9.8884, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9219, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 7, 45, 53, 369040, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'},
  {'unrealizedPL': 10.003, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9216, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 7, 45, 41, 86253, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'}],
 True)
```

If `data[0]` , it will still return the second part but The tuple will become a list where `True` is eliminated.

```
{'trades': [{'id': '9306', 'instrument': 'EUR_GBP', 'price': '0.83150', 'openTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:09.481201403Z', 'initialUnits': '462500', 'initialMarginRequired': '14637.9400', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '462500', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '489.8560', 'marginUsed': '14630.9100', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9307', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:09.839444208Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9306', 'price': '0.83648', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9308', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:10.154967972Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9306', 'price': '0.82857', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9302', 'instrument': 'USD_CAD', 'price': '1.27561', 'openTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:08.344902573Z', 'initialUnits': '-462500', 'initialMarginRequired': '13123.7321', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '-462500', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '-10.3265', 'marginUsed': '13106.5315', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9303', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:08.760908757Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9302', 'price': '1.27060', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9304', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:44:09.114055042Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9302', 'price': '1.27856', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9286', 'instrument': 'GBP_JPY', 'price': '154.857', 'openTime': '2022-01-31T12:39:24.298934946Z', 'initialUnits': '4625', 'initialMarginRequired': '176.0756', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '4625', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '2.1458', 'marginUsed': '175.8277', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9287', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:39:24.608270603Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9286', 'price': '155.361', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9288', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:39:24.941634335Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9286', 'price': '154.556', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9278', 'instrument': 'AUD_USD', 'price': '0.70502', 'openTime': '2022-01-31T12:38:10.153106452Z', 'initialUnits': '462552', 'initialMarginRequired': '9251.0400', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '462552', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '0.0000', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '449.9650', 'marginUsed': '9251.0400', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9279', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:38:10.457435278Z', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9278', 'price': '0.71004', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9280', 'createTime': '2022-01-31T12:38:10.765267979Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9278', 'price': '0.70230', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9229', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34505', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:01.767987144Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9310', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '-0.4036', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '9.2046', 'marginUsed': '28.3384', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9240', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:40:54.539350738Z', 'replacesOrderID': '9230', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9229', 'price': '1.50000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}, 'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9231', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:02.589631870Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '9229', 'price': '1.01000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'state': 'PENDING'}}, {'id': '9219', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34465', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:53.369040131Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9312', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '-0.4036', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '9.6211', 'marginUsed': '28.3384'}, {'id': '9216', 'instrument': 'USD_SGD', 'price': '1.34454', 'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:41.086253690Z', 'initialUnits': '1000', 'initialMarginRequired': '27.9355', 'state': 'OPEN', 'currentUnits': '1000', 'realizedPL': '0.0000', 'financing': '-0.4036', 'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000', 'unrealizedPL': '9.7356', 'marginUsed': '28.3384', 'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9246', 'createTime': '2022-01-24T09:05:54.649091912Z', 'replacesOrderID': '9217', 'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT', 'tradeID': '9216', 'price': '1.50000', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}}], 'lastTransactionID': '9308'}
[{'unrealizedPL': 489.856, 'currentUnits': 462500, 'trade_id': 9306, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 44, 9, 481201, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'EUR_GBP'},
 {'unrealizedPL': -10.3265, 'currentUnits': -462500, 'trade_id': 9302, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 44, 8, 344902, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_CAD'},
 {'unrealizedPL': 2.1458, 'currentUnits': 4625, 'trade_id': 9286, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 39, 24, 298934, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'GBP_JPY'},
 {'unrealizedPL': 449.965, 'currentUnits': 462552, 'trade_id': 9278, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 12, 38, 10, 153106, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'AUD_USD'},
 {'unrealizedPL': 9.2046, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9229, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 8, 1, 1, 767987, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'},
 {'unrealizedPL': 9.6211, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9219, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 7, 45, 53, 369040, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'},
 {'unrealizedPL': 9.7356, 'currentUnits': 1000, 'trade_id': 9216, 'openTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 24, 7, 45, 41, 86253, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'instrument': 'USD_SGD'}]
```

The data was actually return from a function

```
   def open_trades(self):
        url = f"{defs.OANDA_URL}/accounts/{defs.ACCOUNT_ID}/openTrades"
        status_code, data = self.make_request(url)
        
        if status_code != 200:
            return [], False

        if 'trades' not in data:
            return [], True

        trades = [OandaTrade.TradeFromAPI(x) for x in data['trades']]       

        return trades, True
```

The data was acquired from API and needs a key. Thus, I paste the output as above. The function was used in other parts of the program and thus has to keep in current format.

Comment: When I copy-pasted the first block of code and ran `type(data)` I got `<class 'dict'>`.

Comment: this doesn't make sense: you post a very large dict *and* a tuple.  what is your `data` really?  the answer is probably `data = data[0] btw`

Comment: @RoyCohen, the output for the both part is tuple. Yup, first part is dict. However, the original function will return both dict and tuple together

Comment: @2e0byo I have edit the post to show `data[0]`. It will not remove the second part but only remove the `True` in tuple and the tuple become a list

Comment: @bkcollection this still doesn't make any sense.  The code you provide for `data` only assigns a dict to `data` (it evaluates and then throws away a tuple).  Now you say that you get this data from a function which returns a `tuple[dict, tuple]`?  We need to *see* the fn, and where you call it, and what your code *actually* looks like.  we can't guess based on an assignment which clearly isn't what you are actuall doing (since the type of `data` in your question is actuall `dict`, but your second response suggests you are actually operating on your tuple object, and the dict is nowhere.

Comment: @2e0byo. I have added the function to the post. However, it will require API key to get the data and thus I paste the output of the data data

Comment: Your fn returns a list (via the listcomp). What do you want it to return?

Comment: @2e0byo. Only the first part or dict only. However, the fn has to remain the same as it is used in multiple parts of the whole program

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241579/discussion-between-2e0byo-and-bkcollection).